# How to fix this Out OF Memory Exception when Processing a video using EmguCV QueryGrayFrame()

Tags: c#, video, out-of-memory, video-capture, emgucv

I have been digging through this for a while now, but I still can't find the source of the problem yet.

First, please know that all videos are 15 seconds each, 450 frames total. Frames are getting resized later to 50x50.

Using EmguCv, I am using the below routine to get all frames of a video:

```
public void PopulateAllFrames()
    {
        int FramesCount = 0;

        try
        {                 
            FramesCount = (int)capture.GetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT);

            for (int i = 0; i < FramesCount; i++)
            {
                var frame = capture.QueryGrayFrame(); // Error here
                var resized = frame.Resize(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
                AllFrames.Add(resized.Copy());
            }

            capture.Dispose();
            GC.Collect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```

The above works fine when I load any video on a button click:

```
private void SelectAVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        OpenFileDialog OpenFile = new OpenFileDialog();

        if (OpenFile.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {            
            OriginalVideo = new MyVideo(OpenFile.FileName, true);

            OriginalVideo.PopulateAllFrames();     
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {}
}
```

But it does not work **on some videos** when I load a directory of 25 videos. The passed videos are the same videos everytime, and the "errored" videos are also the same every time:

```
private void LoadDirectory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    try
    {
        using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

            if (result == DialogResult.OK && fbd.SelectedPath != null)
            {
                AllVideos = new List<MyVideo>();

                AllVideosFileNames = Directory.GetFiles(fbd.SelectedPath).ToList();

                for (int i = 0; i < AllVideosFileNames.Count(); i++) // loop the rest of the videos, start from the 5th video and till the end
                 {
                    MyVideo CurrentVideo = new MyVideo(AllVideosFileNames[i], false);
                    CurrentVideo.PopulateAllFrames();
                    AllVideos.Add(CurrentVideo);

                 } 
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { }
}
```

I am getting `OutOfMemoryException` whenever I hit `QueryGrayFrame()`, on the same group of videos every time I execute, even if I load only 10 videos. And with no pattern (means error does not pop just on the last 10 indexes.. etc). Knowing that videos are really small, And if I load any of those videos separately, it works fine.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: If you randomize the list of videos before processing, does it still happen on the same videos?

Comment: Your `frame` variable implements IDisposable but you do not dispose it. Same with `resized`.

Comment: @Evk I don't know what to tell you :) Once I added `frame.Dispose()` and `resized.Dispose()` everything worked as expected!

Comment: Maybe answer my Q with some explanation? videos are really really small, why my machine could not handle them without Disposing?

Comment: CC: @Abion47 Thanks !

Comment: The video files are small because of the compression algorithms that video formats use. When you pull all the frames out, you are undoing that compression and are dealing with the video in its rawest format. For example, a 15-second long 720p video with 30 fps could only be a few megabytes as a file, but pull all the images out and suddenly you are dealing with 1,244,160,000 bytes (1.24 GB) of data. So if you don't `Dispose` the frames after using them, you are storing all that data in memory.

Comment: Math for the reference: 1280 Pixel Width * 720 Pixel Height * 3 Channels Per Pixel * 15 Seconds * 30 Frames Per Second = 1,244,160,000 bytes (assuming 8 bits per channel).

Comment: @Abion47 Cool ! Thanks for the reference. I did not think of that for the fact that my videos were 500x500, and I was "guerying" gray frames. For some reason I did not take disposal into consideration. Now I do :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I only needed to `.Dispose()` my variables, as I did not think of that since my videos were small. Turned out they are taking a lot of memory nevertheless. so doing this fixed the problem:

```
for (int i = 0; i < FramesCount; i++)
        {
            var frame = capture.QueryGrayFrame(); // Error here
            var resized = frame.Resize(ImageWidth, ImageHeight, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_LINEAR);
            AllFrames.Add(resized.Copy());
            frame.Dispose();
            resized.Dispose();
        }
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you :)